# spatial weight matrix

Tags: matrix, stata, spatial

I have two Excel files: one file contains information about the unemployment rate in some regions by year and the other contains a matrix of freight flows between these regions by year. Please tell me how to upload these files to Stata and build a spatial matrix of weights in order to calculate the Moran index later

I tried to use the command

```
spatwmat using "data.matrix.xlsx", name(Ws) standardize
```

but Stata does not read this file

That is, in my Excel file there is a matrix for trade flows between regions, but I do not understand how to tell Stata that this is the matrix of weights.